# ren doesn't work for parent folder in BATCH programming

Tags: batch-file, directory, parent, rename

```
set FILENAME1=name1.ini
set FILENAME2=name2.ini
ren %FILENAME1% %FILENAME2%
```

This works

But

```
set FILENAME1=../name1.ini
set FILENAME2=../name2.ini
ren %FILENAME1% %FILENAME2%
```

This doesn't work.

As you can see I simply want to rename something in my parent folder, it says The syntax of the command is incorrect.
Help! Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you navigate to parent folder and rename the file?

Comment: What do you mean by navigating to parent folder? I'm somewhat new to BATCH programming so not very sure about that.

Basically I don't want to pollute the exe folder anymore, so therefore I have this Bat file in another folder within the exe folder.

And, what I want to achieve is as what I was saying in my question.

Comment: How do I close the question? I already figured out the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
set FILENAME1=name1.ini 
set FILENAME2=name2.ini
ren ../%FILENAME1% %FILENAME2%
```

The name you renamed into do not need the parent directory "../"